# Ansible playbook to check user exist or display error message

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

How to check if user is present and

- if present, continue with next task
- if not present display a message saying `Given user does not exist`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the [getent module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html).

```yaml
- name: get root user info
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: root
```

If the user is present, the play will continue. If the user does not exist, the play will fail.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you try to achieve and for further enhancements you could proceed further with reading the account database fully

> *Runs `getent` against one of it's various databases and returns information into the host's facts, in a getent_ prefixed variable*

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    USER: "test"

  tasks:

  - name: Gather available local users
    getent:
      database: passwd

  - name: Show gathered local user names only
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ getent_passwd.keys() | list }}"
    when: ansible_check_mode
```

and later [assert if given expression are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)

```yaml
  - name: Check if local user account '{{ USER }}' exists
    assert:
      that:
        - USER in getent_passwd.keys()
      fail_msg: "Given user not exists!"
      success_msg: "Given user exists."
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Gather available local users] ****************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check if local user account 'test' exists] ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: USER in getent_passwd.keys()
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Given user not exists!
```

It would also be possible to just [`end_play`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) by using

```yaml
  - block:

    - name: Show message
      debug:
        msg: "Given user not exists!"

    - meta: end_play

    when: USER not in getent_passwd.keys()
```

**Thanks to**

- [Is there a way to check that a dictionary key is not defined in Ansible task?](https://serverfault.com/questions/857973/)

**Further Readings**

- [Ansible `getent` query LDAP users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474819/)