# ansible getent query ldap users

Tags: ansible

I try to verify if an LDAP user is available or not on my target host. Below snippet verifies local users fine, however, gives an incorrect result with LDAP users.

```
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - debug:
        msg: User {{ item }} exists.
      loop:
        - root
        - myfid
      when: item in my_users
      vars:
        my_users: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
```

And here is the result:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myhost] => (item=root) => {
    "msg": "User root exists."
}
skipping: [myhost] => (item=myfid)
```

myfid is an existing ldap user - I get the expected result from bash.

How can I verify LDAP users and LDAP users only? For the installation I have to use LDAP users.
How can I halt the playbook if user does not exist?
Thanks!

Comment: When you say, " I get the expected result from bash", exactly what command are you running in bash? Specifically, are you running `getent passwd` and then finding the name in the resulting list, or are you running `getent passwd myfid`?

Comment: @larsks I use: 'getent passwd myfid'  # getent passwd myfid
myfid:*:12015359:12015359:myfid:/home/myfid:/bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

The Ansible `getent` module is just a wrapper around the `getent` command. The problem here is that the way you're calling `getent` in your playbook is different from the way you're calling it on the command line.

Your `getent` task...

```
- getent:
    database: passwd
```

...is the equivalent of running `getent passwd` on the command line. This requires your user database(s) to be *enumerable*, and that depends on detail of your system configuration. If you have a very large number of users in LDAP, you don't necessarily *want* to be able to retrieve the entire list.

It might work better if you rewrite your playbook to match the way you're calling `getent` on the command line, by looking up a specific user. You could do something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # loop over a list of users, calling `getent` for each specific user
    - getent:
        database: passwd
        key: "{{ item }}"
      register: users

      # we want to know the results of this check in subsequent tasks,
      # so we set `failed_when: false` so that the task doesn't fail,
      # and map the `failed` status onto `changed` so that we can
      # check it later on.
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: users is failed

      loop:
        - lars
        - alice

    - debug:
        msg: "User {{ item.item }} exists"
      when: item is not changed
      loop: "{{ users.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

On my system, where I (`lars`) exist and `alice` does not, this produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [getent] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=lars)
changed: [localhost] => (item=alice)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=lars) => {
    "msg": "User lars exists"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=alice) 

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Update**

To look up *only* ldap users, it looks like you can use the `service` option (equivalent to the `-s` command line flag) to restrict the results to the `ldap` service, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # loop over a list of users, calling `getent` for each specific user
    - getent:
        database: passwd
        service: ldap
        key: "{{ item }}"
      register: users

      # we want to know the results of this check in subsequent tasks,
      # so we set `failed_when: false` so that the task doesn't fail,
      # and map the `failed` status onto `changed` so that we can
      # check it later on.
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: users is failed

      loop:
        - user1
        - user2

    - debug:
        msg: "User {{ item.item }} exists"
      when: item is not changed
      loop: "{{ users.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

I can't test the above; I'm curious to know if it works out for you.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I accept your answer because you helped me to understand what was wrong with my approach. However, your script does not produce the required output - namely, to distinguish local users from ldap users.

Comment: You could search LDAP explicitly using the [`ldap_search` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ldap_search_module.html). It's possible the `-s` flag to `getent` (available as the `service` flag in the `getent` module) may allow you to do this with `getent`, but I don't have an environment in which I can test this at the moment.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect my last comment. Let me know if it works!

Comment: TASK [getent] **
ok: [myhost] => (item=myldapser)
ok: [myhost] => (item=mylocaluser)

TASK [debug] **
ok: [myhost] => (item=myldapser) => {
    "msg": "User myldapser exists"
}
ok: [myhost] => (item=mylocaluser) => {
    "msg": "User mylocaluser exists"
}

Comment: I guess the `service` option doesn't work as I expected. Bummer! That leaves the `ldap_search` module as the best option, I guess.

Comment: I found a workaround. getent gives the proper result with ansible.builtin.shell    tasks:
  - name: Check LDAP User
    shell: 
      "getent --service=sss passwd myfid | wc -l"
    register: user_check

  - debug: msg="{{user_check.stdout}}"

Comment: If you pass `service: sss` in the ansible module, does it also work? That should result in the identical command being run.

Comment: Nope, service: ldap and service: sss gave the same result

Comment: @larsks, for a RHEL environment, joined into an MS AD domain and running SSSD, I like to confirm that Ansible `getent` module with `service: sss` is correctly gathering remote AD users.

Comment: @U880D On RHEL joined to KDC service: sss gave "User xxxx exists" for both local and LDAP users.