# Ansible user module check if a user exists or not?

Tags: ansible

The requirement is for Ansible `user` module just check if a user exists and do not take any action.

Does `check_mode` help here? How should such a playbook task be written?

This link, [Ansible playbook to check user exist or display error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472882/ansible-playbook-to-check-user-exist-or-display-error-message)  provides an alternative. Is it possible to get this done with builtin `user` module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell and for the most basic check (i.e. username is there regardless of any other user configuration):

```yaml
---
- name: Check if users exists
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true

  vars:
    users_to_test:
      - daemon  # This one should exist, at least on ubuntu
      - a_non_existing_user

  tasks:
    - name: Check if users exist
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users_to_test }}"
      check_mode: true
      register: test_users

    - name: Report
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "User {{ item.item }} {{ 'exists' if item.state | d('') == 'present' else 'does not exist' }}"
      loop: "{{ test_users.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

Which give on my ubuntu 20 local machine:

```
$ ansible-playbook testuser.yml 

PLAY [Check if users exists] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check if users exist] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=daemon)
changed: [localhost] => (item=a_non_existing_user)

TASK [Report] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=daemon) => {
    "msg": "User daemon exists"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=a_non_existing_user) => {
    "msg": "User a_non_existing_user does not exist"
}
```

Comment: A feasible approach for how to use `check_mode` to implement a reporting (only) task. Even if it was not mentioned for such, I am too using it that way sometimes.

Comment: I inferred that `check if a user exists and do not take any action` means: verify presence and get a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Since Ansible is mainly a Configuration Management Tool in which one can declare a Desired State

> *The requirement is for Ansible `user` module just check if a user exists and do not take any action.*

this is already and mostly the default behavior of the [`user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) module. If the user already exists and there are no changes necessary the module will just return a `changed: false` and reports `OK`. So it will not take any action then.

For a simple check only if a user exists you've found already the [Ansible playbook to check user exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72475117/6771046) via [`getent`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html) module. Please take note that it is not an "alternative" compared to the `user` module.

> *Does `check_mode` help here?*

Since [`check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode) is mainly for [Validating tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html) and

> *Check mode is just a simulation ... it is great for validating configuration management playbooks that run on one node at a time.*

it will mainly depend on what you try to achieve and how a run should behave.

**Further Readings and Q&A**

- [An Ansible playbook for solving a new problem from scratch](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-automation-steps)
- [Ansible: Only disable existing users?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035598/)
- [How to lock a user using Ansible?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17007/)