# Ansible: How to get group details and create group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Looking for Ansible code to create group only if not found with `getent`.

```yaml
- name: Get group
  getent:
  database: group
  key: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
   - developer
   - admin
   - support
```

Comment: That's what the `group` module is already doing by default; it is idempotent. Or are there a lot of information and description missing here?

Answer (score 0):

According [`getent` module – A wrapper to the unix getent utility](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html) in order to gather a list of existing groups, minimal example playbook would provide it

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - getent:
      database: group
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.ansible_facts.getent_group.keys() }}"
```

Since the [`group` module – Add or remove groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/group_module.html) works already [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency), in order to ensure the groups exists, just do

```yaml
- name: Ensure the groups exists
  ansible.builtin.group:
    name: somegroup
    state: present
  loop:
    - admin
    - developer
    - support
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to check user exist or display error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72475117/6771046)
- [Ansible: `user` module check if an user exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75212410/6771046)